# Subclipse not uploading JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

I'm having a bit of trouble making Subclipse work. I've got a working proyect in my local computer and I'm now trying to upload it to a SVN. Everything went great, except that when the other developers do a check out the proyect gets downloaded without the JRE System Library so the complete proyect shows an exclamation mark.
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JRE System Library entry is just a pointer to the locally installed JRE. If you use an absolute path to the library, then you should change that to include just an Execution Environment, where every developer then can configure that Execution Environment to his local path of the JRE.